# New users must comment when requesting username

Tags: admin, users, spam

Does any one know of a Plug in that will help with reducing the number of unknown user requests to my site?

current when a new user requests access I can only see an email address and username. Is it possible to ask the user to also make a short comment, to make it easier to see what is spam and what is valid?

Regards

aaron

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *captcha* plugin that requires users to type a short phrase or random letters in order to register on your site.

An example of one of these plugins is the WP-reCAPTCHA, found at:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-recaptcha/

Or you can use a plugin such as CIMY User Extra Fields to add fields to a user profile and registration screen:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/

Comment: I have a few captcha plug in and all good, but some spam bots still get past them.  I was thinking mre to get user to enter a comment asking for the access.

Comment: - There are plugins you can use to add extra fields to registration. Provided a new link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want core php codes then i can help you out but i'm not good in wp queries but if you know then you can check first in database with email id of user that is he comment before like we do in core php `$result=mysql_query("select * from wp_comments where comment_author_email=THAT-USER-EMAIL-ID"); if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) { Allow user to register } else { show error }`